# How to show a datapoint selected in ApexCharts onload event?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

How can we show a datapoint selected in a pie or donut charts while using ApexCharts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using "toggleDataPointSelection" function inside ApexCharts on animationEnd event. Here is the example:

`chart: {type: 'donut',events: {animationEnd: function(ctx) { ctx.toggleDataPointSelection(0) }}},`

Please note toggleDataPointSelection takes a parameter which is the index of the datapoint you want to show as selected.